# How to save array of objects in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a Client Table, relation Table  and Items Table

Now 1 client can have 1 relation but can have multiple Items .

I have this in my client Entity

```
            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "relationId")
private Relation relationId;
```

So now when ever i create a new client ,a new row in a relation Table also created and the Id for that relation Table saves in the column "relationId" inside my Client Table.

But how can I do the same thing for Items Column inside my Clients Table, because when I create a client, that client may have, multiple items, so we can have multiple rows created for that single client.

So maybe I need something like 1,2,5  in my itemsColumn inside the Client Table.

or any other approach..

For this above approach i need to have my itemsColumn of type Array , But how to achive this , i.e how i can save array of Objects in mySql.

Any thoughts to resolve this issue of mine with any approach .

Comment: Do you have a one-to-many association (i.e. one client has several items, and one item belongs to one client), or a many-to-many association (i.e. one client has several items, and each item can belong to several clients)? Depending on what the association is, use the appropriate annotation: OneToMany or ManyToMany.

Comment: its oneToMany , i defined this , but when a client created (i.e one row added in clinet Table, and one row added in Items Table , and that item Id ,saves in client Table inside Item Column,and then Whenever i fetch that client to display , this will gives me the object of that client which includes an Id of that Item, BUT when its 2 items against one client at the time of saving , means two Ids  ,suppose 1 and 2 for item1 and item2, so how these 2 ids will be saving in my client Table

Comment: what data type should i assign to my column clientsItem , inside my client table , and while in mapping as u see in my question i have the Relation relationId , so what should i return for items.

Comment: The 2 IDS won't be stored in the client table. They will be stored either in a join table, or in the Item table. Just like you have a OneToMany association between Relation and Client, and the association is materialized the the relation_id in the client table.

Comment: It should be a `@OneToMany private Set<Item>`.